# Add concatenated results to table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How do you insert the result of two concatenated columns from a table into the same table as a new column?

Here's the statement I'd like to add to the table:

`SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name AS full_name
FROM emps;`

I tried using an INSERT INTO statement but am at a loss...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do:

```
update emps
    set full_name = first_name || ' ' || last_name;
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I've been trying to do it in one command. I should just make the new column name and then use your command after. i'll try it now.

Comment: Why not use a virtual column?

Answer (score 2):

Since it a computed column, and you are on `11g`, so just use a `VIRTUAL COLUMN`.

Something like,

`full_name  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (first_name || ' ' || last_name) VIRTUAL`

**There is no need of an overhead to create another column and then update it. Oracle will do this automatically for you.**

Comment: It's a good idea - but it might not *necessarily* be correct for this situation.

Comment: I agree, depends on the business need more than technical. This is what I think right now.